# How can I declare a Boolean parameter in SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I declare a Boolean parameter in SQL statement?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The same way you declare any other variable, just use the `bit` type:

```
DECLARE @MyVar bit
Set @MyVar = 1  /* True */
Set @MyVar = 0  /* False */

SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE MyBitColumn = @MyVar
```

Note this is semantically different from a true boolean. The 1/0 values won't always just map to true/false the way you might expect.

Comment: Although bit is the closest match, bit isn't boolean. You can't do this in TSQL, for instance:
    IF @isDeleted ....
You must do this instead
    IF @ isDeleted = 1 ....

Answer (score 32):

SQL Server recognizes `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` as `bit` values. So, use a `bit` data type!

```
declare @var bit
set @var = 'true'
print @var
```

That returns `1`.

Comment: I think in comparison, one needs to do (@var = 1) NOT JUST (@var), at least in the version I use, especially for SSRS reports (if TSQL is used there)  -- very similar comment to that by Darren Griffith above...